# Deployment of multi-project MVC4 solution to Azure fails

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, git, deployment, azure

This is my second deployment to Azure.
First was a simple MVC4 Website with a Database, which I deployed via git. Worked like a charm.

Now I've got the following:
A solution containing three projects.

- Web -> Which is the MVC4 Frontend
- Models -> Contains the Models and the DB Context
- Backend -> MVC4 Project for data administration

All projects are MVC4 (didn't know how to manage this better for the Models project).
In my models project I'm running the code-firt migrations.
The backend is running in the virtual directory: localhost:80/Backend
(works perfect on localhost)
Both the Web and Backend project have references to the Models Project.

Folder structure:
Solution folder contains:
*Web / Models / Backend / MySolution.sln*

The first time I deployed I've created a git repo in the Projects folder (cause it was a single project). Now my repo is in the solution folder.

I'm also uploading files in the Backend and move it to the other project (Web) via the following path:

```
Directory.GetParent(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")).ToString() + DirSeperator + "Web" + DirSeperator + "Store" + DirSeperator;
```

Is this going to a problem on Azure?

**So my loose question is now, how am I deploying this solution?**

---

I've created a Website with Source control in Azure and added a SQL Database to it.

I've managed to push the solution to Azure, 
but on Azure there's the messsage

> Found solution ... with no deployable projects. Deploying files instead.

now.

---

Do you have any good tutorials for me on this problem?

Am I doing it completely wrong? (I think so)

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET and Azure, so it's a bit hard for me to understand.

Thanks,
Tobi

Comment: please include more information: how are you redirecting assemblies? have you created deployable dependancy folder for your project?

Comment: I don't even know what a deployable dependancy folder is :( for Web and Backend Project I've selected "Add Reference" in the context menu and checked my Model Project. That's all I did for now.

Comment: ok, if you right click on MVC project file in solution explorer, you have the option to 'add deployable dependancies'. These dll's are not included in IIS .net V 4 or 4.5 and often have to be copied over for deployment. But don't focus on that exactly. Deploying to Azure involves many check points: such as redirecting your assemblies, possibly adding dependancies, etc. Read thru the guides I included. From there, hopefully you will converge to specific questions

Comment: Thanks. Adding deployable dependencies doesn't work for VS2012 anymore (therefore I can't find the button), see here: [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735553/add-deployable-dependencies-missing-from-vs11-beta) I've read the first 3 guides already, but only the 4th seems to be helpful. I'll give it a try. I don't understand, what I should do with "redirecting assembly versions"?

Comment: I didn't realize you were on VS 2012 (we tried using MVC 4 RC in 2010 but dropped it). that narrows the potential list of issues. I kind of though everything at you in hopes of hitting the issue.

Comment: Hi. I didn't manage to get this working, so I created two Websites on Azure for the 2 deployable Projects (Web, Backend). This works for now, but I don't know how I can upload files to the other project, cause my code from above doesn't work anymore ... (notice: this should be just a temporary solution)

Comment: interesting hack. This gives me something to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've managed to solve my problem.**
Sorry, that I'm answering my own question - hope this doesn't offend anyone.

What I wanted to achieve is not possible with Azure Web Sites, but with Web Roles.
As seen here on [CloudCover](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-37-Multiple-Websites-in-a-Web-Role) and on [StructureTooBig](http://blog.structuretoobig.com/post/2012/01/17/One-Azure-Web-Role-Multiple-Websites.aspx).

So I've created a new Azure Cloud Application (provided by the Azure Tools) in Visual Studio, with a default Web Role, which is my Web Frontend project.
I've added a VirtualApplication to the Web Role with the name "backend" and the physicalDirectory set to my Backend Project path.
Then I've added a VirtualDirectory "store", which I could access from both projects for file uploads.

My WebRole looks like this now:

```
<WebRole name="MvcWebRole1" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web" physicalDirectory="[projectpath]">
    <VirtualApplication name="backend" physicalDirectory="[projectpath]">
    </VirtualApplication>
    <VirtualDirectory name="store" physicalDirectory="[projectpath]">
    </VirtualDirectory>
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
</Endpoints>
<Imports>
  <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
  <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
  <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
</Imports>
```

I'm accessing (read+write) the store now via:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("/Store" + DirSeperator);
```

instead of

```
Directory.GetParent(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")).ToString() + DirSeperator + "Web" + DirSeperator + "Store" + DirSeperator;
```

Which works perfectly on both projects.

So, this solution works and I've already deployed it to production!

**Emerging problems:**

- Web Sites work with *git* integration, but Cloud Services won't (this is very bad for my workflow).
- The deployment takes about 30-45 minutes. Holy ...
- I've had to publish everything again to activate Remote Access and WebDeploy features. And I hope, WebDeploy is going to save time for deploying updates ... as everytime I'm updating now, the complete solution is replaced on server (within the mentioned time span).
- Is there a way to access the data via FTP?

Ciao

Answer (score 1):

**Followup Edit:** I see now, this has more to do with configuring 2 project deploys. You will need to create deployment scripts

I'm not done doing research, but take a look at these posts:

http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38419111245/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart3

http://kellyhpdx.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/deploying-multiple-web-applications-to-a-single-azure-instance-and-applying-web-config-transforms-correctly/

Comment: @artistandsocial, I updated my post to more useful threads dealing specifically with deploying multiple projects from git to Azure. Meanwhile, I'm going to check one of our own repo's with multiple projects and see how we configured for multiple deploys.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your support. I'm working now with a fresh solution (easier to deploy). I've learned a bit about the difference between Web Sites and Web Roles on Azure, and it seems I can't do what I want with Web Sites. So I've created a Web Role and will try the next days to deploy multiple Websites on it (like shown in your second link by Kelly). I've tried it with one Project in it now, which works as expected (although deployment is really slow - takes about 10 minutes). I hope this is the right approach now. Thank you.